# Barnes-Hut force directed layout for Boost Graph library?

Tags: boost, graph, graph-algorithm, force-layout

The default Fruchterman-Reingold algorithm that boost graph library uses for directed graphs takes O(n^2) time, is there any implementation of an O(n log n) layout algorithm like Barnes-Hut for Boost Graph library?